# HTML is displayed after few seconds even the code is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, performance, loading, google-optimize

I've a strange behavior with my web site. 
When I open a page (**any page**) the code is loaded but browser *display the content only after few seconds*.

I've tried to print a console.log to see when it appear, and it appear after the code is loaded, as I expect it to do, but the content of the page is display after few seconds...
This behavior occurs when I switch my web site to a specific language, while with the other language everythings works fine.
The code is the same except for the text.

Do you know why?

Comment: The time delay might be due to loading of custom fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the i18n system you are using require a little time to map the frontend string with translation, without full code snippet that reproduce the issue is difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

no, I've found that the problem is the script of google optimizer...
I loaded the script but I didn't use ga('require', 'optimezer_coded') for this language.

If I remove the script that load optimezer or I insert ga('require', 'optimezer_coded')   it works.